# How does the N1 bootloader works

Tags: android, bootloader, nexus-one, android-source

How does the N1 boot into the bootloader? I'm currently working with aosp gingerbread and would like to know which particular file(s) is/are used to read the buttons (e.g. power button + trackball) that the user press to get into the bootloader.

Is it possible to launch a password protection before the bootloader launches or even disable fastboot itself?

Answer (score 0):

Surely it will be coded onto a ROM chip and hence will not read from any files.
As far as I know there's also no way to flash a new bootloader.